# UISearchBar in UINavigationBar shared between UIViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uisearchbar

I'm trying to replicate the functionality in the Facebook for iOS app where the UISearchBar in the navigation bar is 'shared' between view controllers. For example, tapping on the search bar on the home News Feed view appears to push a new view controller and 'transfer' the search bar to the new view controller. The search bar size is resized and animated alongside view controller transitions (including when using the 'interactive pop' transition, as depicted in the screenshot below). This behaviour is exhibited in various ways throughout the app. Is there a standard way to achieve this behaviour in UIKit, or are Facebook somehow applying custom transitions/animations to the navigation bar and search bar?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having had a quick play with it, first I'd say that the main screen is split into several parts.  Its hard to know what those objects are, but at a guess, I'd say theyve got a UIViewController that just contains the search bar and other 'navigation' elements.  Below that theres another UIViewController that contains the newsfeed, and that is a flexible space in that various other things (custom) can happen in there.  Both of these are likely set as 'ChildViewControllers' within a parent ViewController.  This allows you to for eg, get several UIViewControllers onto the same UIViewController space in interface builder.

Their search bar itself is highly customized and might not even be based on a UISearchBar.  Theyve probably just created a fully custom UIView with a UITextView to type into and lots of other custom animation going on.  Still, you can achieve much of what they are doing by using a UISearchBar.

So going this way, the search bar remains the same search bar, while content changes below.  If you for eg do a search, then the search results appear below, but that same UISearchBar stays visible above.

An alternative approach that I might do if not using ChildViewControllers (I've gone off that method), would be to simply use UIView based objects within a single UIViewController.  So a UISearchBar at the top, probably within a parent UIView.  And another UIView below to contain the feed and everything else.  Again, just search using the single UISearchBar and change the contents of the UIView below as required.